# Schema generation with Simple.Data?

Tags: integration-testing, database-schema, simple.data

Is there a way to perform database **schema generation** with the **Simple.Data** library (similar to how Fluent NHibernate does it)?

If not, is there a way to run **DDL** (Data Definition Language) commands against a database via the **Simple.Data** library?

Currently in some integration tests I am creating a **SQL CE** database on the fly, auto generating the schema (via Fluent NHibernate), running the tests (accessing the database via **Simple.Data**), then deleting the database after the tests run (for cleanup).

It would be nice to be able to perform the DDL stuff using **Simple.Data** and remove the Fluent NHibernate dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using Fluent Migrator for building DB schema (https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/). It's what Simple.Data migrations would probably look like, so there seems little point reinventing the wheel.

Simple.Data 0.10 will have a new InMemory adapter which is schema-less, to reduce testing friction. Will be out by the end of November.